# add multiple pdf files to blobs usng php

Tags: php, mysql

I have to migrate a legacy database up to MySQL using PHP.  One of the components of the old system is a large (>1000) list of attached files (mostly .pdf, some are .doc/.docx).

I have so far done the following:

1. created mysql table, with a blob to contain the file (this method has
   been chosen for valid reasons)
2. imported all the data except the attachments
3. extracted all the attachments into a folder, naming each file with a unique name
4. added and populated in mysql a column containing the unique name of the attachment
5. created a file containing the full names of all the attachments in the folder.

To add a single file is the only solution that I found in stack

But my requirement is to RECURSIVELY go through the list of filenames and find the matching row in mysql, then insert the file from the folder into the blob

example ...

I have a text file with entries like this (filename, date created, size)..

```
024048DE44C-RUE_MA.pdf,05/24/2013,80233 
024048DE44C-RUE.pdf,06/21/2013,85151 
... (1000 more)
```

I have a file with name `024048DE44C-RUE_MA.pdf` in the folder
I have a row column `filename` containing `024048DE44C-RUE_MA.pdf` in mysql database

I think the solution is something like this, but need help in the middle bit.

```
$myfile = fopen("filelist.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
while(!feof($myfile)) {
$attfile =fgets($myfile);
```

...upload the file

```
// Check if a file has been uploaded
    if(isset($_FILES['uploaded_file'])) {
        // Make sure the file was sent without errors
        if($_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] == 0) {
            // Connect to the database
            $dbLink = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'dbase');
            if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                die("MySQL connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
            }

            // Gather all required data
            $name = $dbLink->real_escape_string($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
            $mime = $dbLink->real_escape_string($_FILES['uploaded_file']['type']);
            $data = $dbLink->real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES  ['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']));
            $size = intval($_FILES['uploaded_file']['size']);

            // Create the SQL query
            $query = "
                INSERT INTO `deal_attachment` (
                    `deal_att_name`, `deal_att_mime`, `deal_att_size`, `deal_att_content`, `deal_att_created`
                )
                VALUES (
                    '{$name}', '{$mime}', {$size}, '{$data}', NOW()
                )";

            // Execute the query
            $result = $dbLink->query($query);

            // Check if it was successfull
            if($result) {
                echo 'Success! Your file was successfully added!';
            }
            else {
                echo 'Error! Failed to insert the file'
                   . "<pre>{$dbLink->error}</pre>";
            }
        }
        else {
            echo 'An error accured while the file was being uploaded. '
               . 'Error code: '. intval($_FILES['uploaded_file']['error']);
        }

        // Close the mysql connection
        $dbLink->close();
    }
    else {
        echo 'Error! A file was not sent!';
    }

    }
fclose($myfile);
```

Comment: Do you have the files on the server? Posting all of them seems a lot of extra work, you should upload them using something like ftp and read the directory instead. Then you can delete them when they have been imported.

Comment: The files are already on the server - I need a way to get them into the mysql table.  The solutions that have been given here and elsewhere all have an HTML <form ../form> and <submit> format, which won't work for multiple instances - they do one file at a time with some user action needed.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use mysql LOAD_FILE function if you already have a table with the filename?

```
 UPDATE mytable SET blobdata=LOAD_FILE(concat("/path/to/", filename));
```

Your files need to be on your mysql server in order for it to work.

If your only problem is how to read the CSV file you can do:

```
 list($filename,$date, $size)=explode(",", $attfile);
```

Comment: That's what I'd try, too (with the appropiate WHERE clause(s) of course ;-)). But first with quite a couple of dry runs ....load_file() can be a cranky beast, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file

Comment: I think this is what I have been looking for - will try it.  Thanks

Comment: Question for Adam - the link VolkerK gave says that LOAD_FILE will convert the content into a string - will that not lose the PDF format, making the file unreadable?

Answer (score 0):

Adam's suggestion worked perfectly for me with the important proviso in Windows that file path must contain double backslashes (so you would construct it like this 
        $path = 'c:\\dir\\subdir\\' . trim($filename) ;.

Following snippet of code shows the call ..

```
    $query = "UPDATE `attachments` SET `att_content`=LOAD_FILE('" .$path . "') WHERE `att_name` = '" . $filename ."'" ; 

    $result = mysqli_query($dbcon,$query) ;

// Check if it was successful (maybe add some more insurance by going back to the database to see if the file is there - it can be that no error was reported but LOAD_FILE didn't work (like if the path is invalid)

    if (false === $result) {
         echo mysqli_error($dbcon);
        die ;
    } else  { echo 'Success! Your file was successfully added!'; }
```